What is SAS doing in this (simple?) script?
This is related to a previous question but here my concern is what SAS is being asked to do by the following script (ignoring i/o commands):
proc reg;
model hddt=bloc entry/r p;
output out=new r=residual p=predicted;
run;

The source is a simple demo outlined here. The relevant data is at the bottom of the post (copied from the pdf).
I'd like to replicate the results in MATLAB. I misinterpreted the SAS commands and came up with the following (likely flawed) MATLAB translation:
data = readtable('data.txt', "VariableNamesLine" ,1);
[pw,wtbl,stats] = anova1(data.HDDT,data.BLOC);

Despite omitting one factor (Entry) referred to in the SAS script ("model hddt=bloc entry/r p;"), my naive translation gives a result similar to that shown in the demo pdf:
Source     SS      df     MS       F     Prob>F   
 -----------------------------------------------
Groups     1.20463    2   0.6023   0.24   0.7893
Error    220.89537   87   2.53903                
Total    222.10000     89                          

My MATLAB script:
Source     SS      df     MS       F     Prob>F
-----------------------------------------------
Groups     1.067    2   0.53333   0.21   0.8111
Error    221.033   87   2.54061                
Total    222.1     89                          

The similarity seems fortuitous since I excluded factor "Entry" that appears in the SAS script. But if I include factors "Entry" and "Bloc" in MATLAB the output becomes
>> aov = anova(data(:,{'BLOC','HDDT','ENTRY'}),'HDDT~ENTRY+BLOC');
>> aov

aov = 

2-way anova, constrained (Type III) sums of squares.

HDDT ~ 1 + BLOC + ENTRY

             SumOfSquares    DF    MeanSquares      F         pValue  
             ____________    __    ___________    ______    __________

    BLOC        1.0667        2      0.53333      2.8293      0.067231
    ENTRY        210.1       29       7.2448      38.433    3.1661e-28
    Error       10.933       58      0.18851                          
    Total        222.1       89                                       

This is evidently a 2-Way ANOVA.
I am doubly confused now. I don't have access to SAS so cannot verify that the output in the pdf matches that expected based on the SAS script and the input data. That would be a first step to clearing the confusion. If it does not match then ideally it might be useful to know how the output was generated (for instance what factors were included) and how this can be replicated in MATLAB.
The following is a snapshot of the header with the output SAS model predictions according to the pdf:

I'd like to understand what the SAS script is supposed to be doing to understand what changes I need to make to the MATLAB script.
Thanks for any assistance.

The data (data.txt):
PLOT BLOC ENTRY HDDT HT LODG YIELD MOIST
3501 1 8 32 84.5 3 46.8 21.5
3502 1 30 32 82.5 3 78.9 19.8
3503 1 7 31 73.5 3 68.5 20.7
3504 1 26 36 64.5 1 64.5 16.7
3505 1 13 33 75.5 2 69.8 16.4
3506 1 18 31 76.0 2 74.5 16.7
3507 1 27 31 78.0 2 85.5 18.0
3508 1 4 34 81.5 4 67.3 16.4
3509 1 29 30 72.0 2 77.4 16.2
3510 1 19 30 80.5 2 55.5 15.3
3511 1 23 34 70.0 4 68.4 15.0
3512 1 5 33 85.0 5 64.2 13.8
3513 1 2 32 87.0 4 71.2 14.7
3514 1 22 35 79.0 4 62.0 13.3
3515 1 25 36 89.5 4 66.0 14.8
3516 1 6 31 83.0 2 77.3 13.6
3517 1 17 33 83.5 3 99.4 16.6
3518 1 3 32 84.0 3 79.9 16.2
3519 1 24 33 82.5 1 83.1 18.0
3520 1 21 32 80.5 1 84.1 19.4
3521 1 20 31 80.5 2 81.5 19.6
3522 1 16 31 75.5 1 65.1 16.0
3523 1 1 32 88.0 3 67.3 19.4
3524 1 14 33 82.0 2 72.9 18.5
3525 1 28 31 79.5 1 89.9 20.6
3526 1 10 31 85.0 3 82.6 20.8
3527 1 11 31 89.0 2 70.0 16.1
3528 1 15 33 75.5 1 77.3 18.9
3529 1 9 33 79.0 2 82.5 16.1
3530 1 12 32 105.0 2 57.4 16.2
3531 2 23 34 72.0 5 69.7 16.5
3532 2 8 32 88.5 3 79.7 16.4
3533 2 28 31 81.0 1 87.6 16.0
3534 2 6 32 81.5 2 70.3 15.8
3535 2 18 30 81.0 2 74.6 13.7
3536 2 2 33 84.5 3 70.7 15.3
3537 2 20 31 86.5 5 79.5 16.6
3538 2 9 32 79.5 3 80.0 13.4
3539 2 13 33 79.0 2 68.7 14.6
3540 2 27 31 73.5 3 78.2 15.4
3541 2 30 32 82.5 2 74.7 16.4
3542 2 21 33 77.0 2 72.5 16.1
3543 2 25 35 84.0 2 72.6 16.0
3544 2 12 32 93.5 3 60.1 16.0
3545 2 16 31 69.5 3 65.2 15.8
3546 2 29 30 72.5 1 82.7 18.4
3547 2 17 33 82.5 4 79.1 17.1
3548 2 14 33 80.0 2 74.5 19.4
3549 2 10 32 76.5 2 81.4 17.2
3550 2 26 36 66.5 1 50.7 22.6
3551 2 5 33 80.0 2 52.9 22.8
3552 2 7 32 77.0 2 75.1 21.3
3553 2 15 33 76.0 1 67.2 19.5
3554 2 24 33 86.5 4 77.9 18.3
3555 2 19 30 84.0 3 72.7 15.9
3556 2 3 33 85.0 3 73.9 17.4
3557 2 1 33 87.0 4 70.6 18.3
3558 2 4 34 86.0 5 70.1 16.0
3559 2 22 35 81.5 6 57.4 16.2
3560 2 11 31 92.0 3 63.3 15.1
3561 3 21 32 83.0 2 83.0 15.6
3562 3 22 34 85.0 6 56.6 13.7
3563 3 14 33 85.0 4 83.9 14.7
3564 3 7 32 86.5 4 80.6 15.5
3565 3 27 31 82.0 2 96.5 14.8
3566 3 6 32 82.5 2 70.4 15.6
3567 3 26 37 73.0 1 72.4 16.2
3568 3 4 35 85.0 4 80.1 16.0
3569 3 25 37 88.5 3 77.6 16.0
3570 3 9 33 88.0 2 80.5 15.6
3571 3 2 32 83.5 2 79.5 16.6
3572 3 16 31 73.5 1 70.0 16.1
3573 3 24 33 83.5 3 85.7 17.8
3574 3 18 31 82.5 2 73.9 17.4
3575 3 10 32 85.5 3 95.7 17.7
3576 3 15 33 78.5 2 78.8 19.9
3577 3 23 35 76.0 5 74.4 19.5
3578 3 17 33 82.0 3 77.3 18.9
3579 3 13 33 77.5 2 72.4 16.2
3580 3 1 33 92.0 4 67.4 16.2
3581 3 30 32 86.0 4 86.5 19.4
3582 3 28 32 75.5 2 89.4 16.7
3583 3 29 30 76.5 1 72.2 19.3
3584 3 11 31 86.5 2 55.6 15.2
3585 3 5 33 80.5 3 63.0 15.5
3586 3 8 32 79.5 3 74.2 14.1
3587 3 12 32 103.0 2 60.9 14.9
3588 3 3 33 83.0 3 72.9 15.7
3589 3 19 30 83.5 3 76.8 14.1
3590 3 20 30 89.0 4 80.4 15.7


Notice that in the SAS output the model has df=2 and each effect has df=1 continuous variables.  2-factor regression might be an acceptable name.
In your ANOVA model you are treating the effects as discrete variables. bloc 3 levels with df=2 entry 30 levels df=29.  2-factor ANOVA.
I think the correct model would treat BLOC as a CLASS variable and entry as continuous.  Analysis of covariance, ANOVA with a continuous effect.
proc glm;
   class bloc;
   model hddt = bloc entry;
   run;


Thanks, yes, that was the problem, not knowing SAS I assumed the script was applying a standard ANOVA with categorical variables but it was a linear regression (the "reg" keyword should have given it away but). I was going to edit my post to reflect this and ask instead what reason one might have to apply regression instead of ANOVA here. I am still looking into the details.
